# Find all text files not containing some text string

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm on **Python 2.7.1** and I'm trying to identify all text files that **don't** contain some text string.

The program seemed to be working at first but whenever I add the text string to a file, it keeps coming up as if it doesn't contain it (false positive). When I check the contents of the text file, the string is clearly present.

The code I tried to write is

```
def scanFiles2(rdir,sstring,extens,start = '',cSens = False): 
    fList = []
    for fol,fols,fils in os.walk(rdir): 
        fList.extend([os.path.join(rdir,fol,fil) for fil in fils if fil.endswith(extens) and fil.startswith(start)]) 
    if fList: 
        for fil in fList: 
            rFil = open(fil) 
            for line in rFil: 
                if not cSens: 
                    line,sstring = line.lower(), sstring.lower() 
                if sstring in line:
                    fList.remove(fil) 
                    break
            rFil.close() 
    if fList:
        plur = 'files do' if len(fList) > 1 else 'file does'
        print '\nThe following %d %s not contain "%s":\n'%(len(fList),plur,sstring) 
        for fil in fList: 
            print fil 
    else: 
        print 'No files were found that don\'t contain %(sstring)s.'%locals() 
scanFiles2(rdir = r'C:\temp',sstring = '!!syn',extens = '.html', start = '#', cSens = False)
```

I guess there's a flaw in the code but I really don't see it.

*UPDATE*

The code still comes up with many false positives: files that **do** contain the search string but are identified as not containing it.

Could **text encoding** be an issue here? I prefixed the search string with `U` to account for Unicode encoding but it didn't make any difference.

Does Python in some way **cache** file contents? I don't think so but that could somewhat account for files to still pop up after having been corrected.

Could some kind of **malware** cause symptoms like these? Seems highly unlikely to me but I'm kinda desperate to get this fixed.

Comment: i've tried as it is and it works for me (just changed "extens" and "rdir" to match my current env)

Comment: @le_vine: that's great but for me it still includes a handful of files that **do** include the search string. I should add that the search string was recently added to them. Any idea what may be going on? As if Python gets the file contents from cache instead of disk or something...

Comment: Naming convention used in the code is not the best. There are too much `fil`, `fLi` in the code. Try to read the code out loud. Try to use names from the documentation for corresponding functions e.g.,  `dirpath, dirnames, filenames` instead of `fol, fols, fils`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modifying element while iterating the list cause unexpected results:

For example:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,4,6,3,8,0,5]
>>> for n in lst:
...     if n % 2 == 0:
...         lst.remove(n)
...
>>> lst
[1, 4, 3, 0, 5]
```

**Workaround** iterate over copy

```
>>> lst = [1,2,4,6,3,8,0,5]
>>> for n in lst[:]:
...     if n % 2 == 0:
...         lst.remove(n)
...
>>> lst
[1, 3, 5]
```

---

Alternatively, you can append valid file path, instead of removing from the whole file list.

Modified version (appending file that does not contian `sstring` instead of removing):

```
def scanFiles2(rdir, sstring, extens, start='', cSens=False): 
    if not cSens: 
        # This only need to called once.
        sstring = sstring.lower() 
    fList = []
    for fol, fols, fils in os.walk(rdir): 
        for fil in fils: 
            if not (fil.startswith(start) and fil.endswith(extens)):
                continue
            fil = os.path.join(fol, fil)
            with open(fil) as rFil:
                for line in rFil: 
                    if not cSens: 
                        line = line.lower()
                    if sstring in line:
                        break
                else:
                    fList.append(fil)
    ...
```

- `list.remove` takes O(n) time, while `list.append` takes O(1). See [Time Complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).
- Use `with` statement if possible.

Comment: @Ray, `glob.glob` does not recurse. could make use of `glob.glob`, but file list is already got by `os.walk`, so it seems unnecessary.  Do you mean [`fnmatch.fnamtch`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch)?

Comment: @falsetru: of course! You shouldn't iterate over a list while modifying it! The other suggestions are **very helpful** too. I'll follow all of them. Does the `with` statement render `rFil.close()` obsolete? Thx a million, you've no idea how much I needed this to work!

Comment: @RubenGeert, `with` statement take care of closing the file object. See [PEP 343: The 'with' statement](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement).

Comment: I'd use `yield fil` instead of `fList.append`. And extract code that determines whether the file should be kept into a separate function. Then current `scanFile2` would perform easily task: take `start, extens, match` and yield corresponding paths. Or `match()` could be moved outside. Why do you use `path.join(rdir, fol, fil)` instead of `path.join(fol, fil)`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Thank you for comment. I updated the code to use `path.join(fol, fil)`.

Answer (score 1):

Falsetru already showed you why you should not remove lines from a list while looping over it; list iterators do not and cannot update their counter when a list is shortened, so if item 3 was processed but you removed that item, the next iteration item 4 was previously located at index 5.

List comprehension version using [`fnmatch.filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) and [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a filter `lambda` for case insensitive matching:

```
import fnmatch

def scanFiles2(rdir, sstring, extens, start='', cSens=False):
    lfilter = sstring.__eq__ if cSens else lambda l, s=sstring.lower(): l.lower() == s
    ffilter = '{}*{}'.format(start, extens)
    return [os.path.join(r, fname)
            for r, _, f in os.walk(rdir)
            for fname in fnmatch.filter(f, ffilter)
            if not any(lfilter(l) for l in open(os.path.join(root, fname)))]
```

but perhaps you'd be better off sticking to a more readable loop:

```
def scanFiles2(rdir, sstring, extens, start='', cSens=False):
    lfilter = sstring.__eq__ if cSens else lambda l, s=sstring.lower(): l.lower() == s
    ffilter = '{}*{}'.format(start, extens)
    result = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(rdir):
        for fname in fnmatch.filter(files, ffilter):
            fname = os.path.join(r, fname)
            with open(fname) as infh:
                if not any(lfilter(l) for l in infh):
                    result.append(fname)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that opens the searching up for using regular expressions (although just using `grep` with appropriate options would still be better):

```
import mmap
import os
import re
import fnmatch

def scan_files(rootdir, search_string, extension, start='', case_sensitive=False):
    rx = re.compile(re.escape(search_string), flags=re.I if not case_sensitive else 0)
    name_filter = start + '*' + extension
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for fname in fnmatch.filter(files, name_filter):
            with open(os.path.join(root, fname)) as fin:
                try:
                    mm = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
                except ValueError:
                    continue # empty files etc.... include this or not?
                if not next(rx.finditer(mm), None):
                    yield fin.name
```

Then use `list` on that if you want the names materialised or treat it as you would any other generator...

Answer (score 1):

Please do not write a python program for that. This program already exists. Use grep:

```
grep * -Ilre 'main' 2> /dev/null
99client/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
99client/taxis-android/build/incremental/mergeResources/production/merger.xml
99client/taxis-android/build/incremental/mergeResources/production/inputs.data
99client/taxis-android/build/incremental/mergeResources/production/outputs.data
99client/taxis-android/build/incremental/mergeResources/release/merger.xml
99client/taxis-android/build/incremental/mergeResources/release/inputs.data
99client/taxis-android/build/incremental/mergeResources/release/outputs.data
99client/taxis-android/build/incremental/mergeResources/debug/merger.xml
99client/taxis-android/build/incremental/mergeResources/debug/inputs.data
(...)
```

http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#Introduction

If you need the list in python, simply execute grep from it and collect the result.